# Mi archivo css no pone background en mi archivo php

Tags: php, html, css

Este es mi archivo php, como ven en el body tiene la clase paginaphp y ademas el link de css

```
<?php

$conex = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die("No se pudo realizar la Conexion");
mysqli_select_db($conex,"cosmeticosdb") or die("Error con el acceso a la base de datos");

session_start();

$id_usuario=$_SESSION['id_usuario'];

$consulta_sql="SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE idUsuario='$id_usuario'";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conex,$consulta_sql) or die(mysqli_error($conex,$consulta_sql));
$resultado_obtenido=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
$nomUsu = $resultado_obtenido['nomUsu'];
$conUsu = $resultado_obtenido['conUsu'];
$id_usuario = $resultado_obtenido['idUsuario']

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cosméticos Rosa | Página del Usuario</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="webIcon.png">
</head>
<body class="paginaphp">
    <h1 class="enca1">Página principal</h1>
    <p class="parrafo1">Usuario: <?php echo $_SESSION['id_usuario']; ?></p>
    <p class="parrafo2">Nombre: <?php echo $_SESSION['nombre_usuario'];?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Este es mi archivo css, como ven el body lleva la referencia de la clase de php, pero a la hora de ejecutar y llegar a esta pagina no se muestra el background

```
body.indexphp{
    background-image: url("cosmeticosback.jpg");
}
body.carritophp{
    background-image: url("carritocosback.jpg");
}

body.paginaphp{
    background-image: url("pagina_usuarioback.jpg");
}

h1.enca1{
    text-align: center;
    color: #f4424b;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: Segoe Script;
}

h1{
    text-align: center;
    color: #f4424b;
    font-size: 100px;
    font-family: Segoe Script;
}

p{
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 375px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: Segoe Script;
    color: #000000;
}

p.parrafo1{
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #000;
}

p.parrafo2{
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Hola Nicolás, has comprobado que la ruta de la imagen sea correcta?

Comment: Si esta en la misma carpeta que se encuentran los archivos, la extensión de la imagen es la misma junto con el nombre

Comment: Te lanza algún error? se puede visualizar en consola (apretando F12), si te arroja un error **404** es que tal vez no estás haciendo bien la referencia a tu archivo de estilos o a tu imagen.

Comment: Es raro, si la ruta es correcta y estás cargando bien el CSS tendría que aparecer, ya que el selector y la propiedad es correcta. Prueba con background, pero igual te tendría que funcionar como lo tienes ahora.

Comment: Ya se arreglo, la verdad no se como pero ahora si lo reconoce y pone el background, igual gracias por sus comentarios :).